# Kubernetes pod cannot connect to service for another port

Tags: kubernetes, redis, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to use the dns system of Google Kubernetes to make one pod (a web-backend) connect to another pod and service (in this case Redis).

When I check the DNS in the cluster, I get this:

```
[ root@curl:/ ]$ nslookup redis-service
Server:    10.40.0.10
Address 1: 10.40.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      redis-service
Address 1: 10.40.2.59 redis-service.default.svc.cluster.local
[ root@curl:/ ]$
```

In my application, I would set the REDIS_HOST url to `redis-service.default.svc.cluster.local`.

Unfortunatedly, the logs say it cannot connect:
[image]
(also with http:// in front).

Do I miss a setting to make these pods able to communicate using this address? This address is predicable, that is why.

[image]

Comment: Could you add a service printout (kubectl get svc -A)?

Comment: See original post... on phone I had to make a screenshot...

Comment: Is your app the zzapps-xxx? As you are running in the same namespace, can you connect with just "redis-service"?

Comment: try with just service name if you are in same namespace or else you can also try deploying the redis-cli and check

Comment: See my answer below. Harsh' comment worked, but I also saw that changing to Cluster IP made my first effort work.

Comment: Does it work now ? Were you able to find a solution ? It's not clear from your answer (to your own post) that it works as you want it to.

Comment: Yes it works now.
It works when using servicename
It works when using ClusterIP

Answer (score 1):

I found 2 things that work:

- Change the service to ClusterIP instead of NodePort.
- @harshmanvar in the comments mentioned, when just using the servicename it also works.

I am not exactly sure why, would like to understand this behaviour.